# How to write Count Query In jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am converting Pure SQL to jOOQ now I have this

```
("SELECT Count(*) Count From Table ");
```

I have to write this in jOOQ how can we write it?

```
selectQueryRecord.addSelect(Here Count Function );
selectQueryRecord.addFrom(Table);
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to implement what you're requesting is this, by using [`selectCount()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#selectCount%28%29):

```java
int count = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectCount()
   .from(Table)
   .fetchOne(0, int.class);
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly express the [`count()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count%28%29) function:

```java
int count = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(DSL.count())
   .from(Table)
   .fetchOne(0, int.class);
```

Or, you can use this, if you don't like mapping the value:

```java
int count =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .fetchValue(selectCount().from(Table));
```

There's another alternative for fetching a [`count(*)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count%28%29) of any arbitrary `select` expression, which helps you avoid specifying the result column index and type in the above `fetchOne()` method. This uses [`fetchCount()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchCount%28org.jooq.Select%29):

```java
int count =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .fetchCount(DSL.selectFrom(Table));
```

Beware, though, that this renders a nested select like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT a, b, ... FROM Table)
```

Comment: Can i use same transaction variable which i am suing through out in my code

Comment: What's the "transaction" variable? But maybe, you should ask a new question for that...

Comment: 'Transaction transfeeTransfer = Transaction.current();'

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates. From your other question(s) I suspect that this is somehow related to a jOOQ `DSLContext` type. But please ask a new Stack Overflow question (and/or write to the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user)) for questions related to transaction handling

Comment: @LukasEder, why isn't a `long` used here?

Comment: @GarretWilson: It probably would've been a better choice, or even `BigInteger`. For historic reasons, a couple of these types are `int` or `Integer` to match pre-JDBC-4.2's usage of `int` for counts. In any case, in 98% of the cases, you won't need to count more than 2G records, so that might be a minor annoyance...

Comment: @LukasEder: Sitting here finishing a glass of wine, the API designer part of me responds: 1) It probably should have always been `long`, even if JDBC used an int (there is no need to "match" JDBC if a `long` is more appropriate and accommodates an int), and 2) I hope "we" can change it eventually, even though this does not affect me in any way right now---maybe someday it might! :) Anyway, I was just curious and thanks for the answer---and for the great library.

Comment: @GarretWilson: It may be the wine talking out of you... but you're right :) and yes, there have been a couple of silly design decisions. Yet, they're there and we're doing semantic versioning so we cannot get rid of them very soon. But I realised that we don't have an issue yet to fix this particular case, so here it is, planned for jOOQ 4.0: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3714

Comment: @LukasEder: Not "silly", just a tiny oversight. Cheers, and thanks for the bug.

Comment: @JeanValjean: Thanks for your edit, but the code was correct

Comment: @LukasEder that's true, I was drunk I guess!

Comment: @LukasEder I see that you have used primitive *int* in your query above. Any side effect or performance issue with using wrapper Integer in Java?

Comment: @realPK: For a single count operation? I don't think so... But perhaps you have a much more specific question? In that case, why not ask a new question? :)

Comment: fectchOne method will return null,is that not throw error when use fetchOne(0,int.class)?

Comment: @Q10Viking When mapping a column value to `int.class`, jOOQ will never throw a NPE, but use the `int` type's default value instead, which is `0`. So, while `fetchOne()` might return `null` (if there are no results), and `fetchOne(0)` might return `null` (if there are no results, or the value at position `0` is `null`), `fetchOne(0, int.class)` will return `0` in those cases.

Comment: @LukasEder with jooq 3.14 and nullable annotations intellij yields a warning that unboxing might throw NPE while this is actually not possible in this case.

Comment: @oshai: Can you please create an issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Comment: @LukasEder submitted here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10831

Answer (score 5):

I use the following syntax for this:

```java
import org.jooq.impl.DSL.count

... 

int count = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectCount()
   .from(Table)
   .fetchOne(count());
```

This is less verbose and simpler.

Lukas's answer dates from 2013, maybe this solution did not exist at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution We have to use like this

```
  selectQueryRecord.fetchCount();
```

Comment: Deprecated as of JooQ 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

`Integer count = DSL.selectCount().from(Table).where(Table.FIELD.eq(value)).fetchOneInto(Integer.class);`

Answer (score -2):

#### NOTE:

> Deprecated. - 3.5.0 - [#3356] - This method is being removed as it is
> confusingly different from all the other types of ResultQuery.fetch()
> methods, in that it modifies the original Select statement by wrapping
> it. In particular, this method can be easily confused with
> ResultQuery.fetch(Field), or more concretely fetch(count()), which has
> an entirely different semantics. Use DSLContext.fetchCount(Select)
> instead. Execute this query in the context of its attached executor
> and return a COUNT(*) value.

I think the proper way to write get the count would be like this:

```
 SelectQuery<Record> selectQueryCount = transaction.selectQuery();
 selectQueryCount.addFrom(Table);
 
 Result<Record> resultObject = selectQueryRecord.fetchCount();
```

Comment: `.fetchCount()` **is deprecated now** @Lukas Elder's answer is the correct one now. Not this one.